# React Three Fiber elements not loading in mobile browsers

Tags: reactjs, three.js, tailwind-css, react-three-fiber

I have used react three fiber to render a **computer**, a few **balls**, and a 3d model of the **Earth**.

The earth seems to load fine while the computer doesn't load and makes the whole hero section go white after a while.

The balls on the other hand, after every reload some load and some dont.

> Mobile browsers I tried it in: Chrome, Brave, Firefox (breaks in all of them)

> PC browsers I tried it in: Chrome, Brave, Firefox (works fine in all of them)

This is the website: https://curran.co.in/
This is github repo: https://github.com/Curran-C/webdev-portfolio

**code for the computer:**

```
//imports
//suspence allows us to add a loader when something is loading
import { Suspense, useState, useEffect } from "react";

// gives us a canvas to place things one
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";

// OrbitControls - Allows the camera to orbit around an object
// Preload - ?
// useGLTF - Allows us to import 3D models
import { OrbitControls, Preload, useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";

import CanvasLoader from "../Loader";

//Component function
const Computers = ({ isMobile }) => {
  // importing the 3d model using useGLTF
  const computer3D = useGLTF("./desktop_pc/scene.gltf");

  //return
  return (
    <mesh>
      <hemisphereLight intensity={0.5} groundColor="black" />
      <pointLight intensity={1} />
      <spotLight
        position={[-20, 50, 10]}
        angle={0.12}
        prenumbra={1}
        intensity={1}
        castShadow
        shadow-mapSize={1024}
      />
      <primitive
        object={computer3D.scene}
        scale={isMobile ? 0.7 : 0.75}
        position={isMobile ? [0, -3, -2.2] : [0, -3.25, -1.5]}
        rotation={[-0.01, -0.2, 0]}
      />
    </mesh>
  );
};

const ComputersCanvas = () => {
  // states
  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(false);

  //side effects
  useEffect(() => {
    const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 500px)");

    setIsMobile(mediaQuery.matches);
    const handleMediaQueryChange = (e) => {
      setIsMobile(e.matches);
      console.log(isMobile);
    };

    mediaQuery.addEventListener("change", handleMediaQueryChange);

    return () => {
      mediaQuery.removeEventListener("change", handleMediaQueryChange);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <Canvas
      frameloop="demand"
      shadows
      camera={{ position: [20, 3, 5], fov: 25 }} //setting where the user is looking at the object from [x,y,z]
      gl={{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true }}
    >
      <Suspense fallback={<CanvasLoader />}>
        <OrbitControls
          enableZoom={false}
          maxPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
          minPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
        />
        <Computers isMobile={isMobile} />
      </Suspense>

      <Preload all />
    </Canvas>
  );
};

export default ComputersCanvas;
```

**code for the balls:**

```
import { Suspense } from "react";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import {
  Decal,
  Float,
  OrbitControls,
  Preload,
  useTexture,
} from "@react-three/drei";
import CanvasLoader from "../Loader";

const Ball = (props) => {
  const [decal] = useTexture([props.imgUrl]);
  return (
    <Float speed={1.75} rotationIntensity={1} floatIntensity={2}>
      <ambientLight intensity={0.25} />
      <directionalLight position={[0, 0, 0.05]} />
      <mesh castShadow receiveShadow scale={2.75}>
        <icosahedronGeometry args={[1, 1]} />
        <meshStandardMaterial
          color="#fff8eb"
          polygonOffset
          polygonOffsetFactor={-1}
          flatShading
        />
        <Decal
          position={[0, 0, 1]}
          rotation={[2 * Math.PI, 0, 6.25]}
          flatShading
          map={decal}
        />
      </mesh>
    </Float>
  );
};

const BallCanvas = ({ icon }) => {
  return (
    <Canvas frameloop="demand" gl={{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true }}>
      <Suspense fallback={<CanvasLoader />}>
        <OrbitControls enableZoom={false} />
        <Ball imgUrl={icon} />
      </Suspense>

      <Preload all />
    </Canvas>
  );
};

export default BallCanvas;
```

**code for the earth:**

```
import { Suspense } from "react";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { OrbitControls, Preload, useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";

import CanvasLoader from "../Loader";

const Earth = () => {
  const earth = useGLTF("./planet/scene.gltf");

  return (
    <primitive object={earth.scene} scale={2.5} position-y={0} rotation-y={0} />
  );
};

const EarthCanvas = () => {
  return (
    <Canvas
      shadows
      frameloop="demand"
      gl={{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true }}
      camera={{
        fov: 45,
        near: 0.1,
        far: 200,
        position: [-4, 3, 6],
      }}
    >
      <Suspense fallback={<CanvasLoader />}>
        <OrbitControls
          autoRotate
          enableZoom={false}
          maxPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
          minPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
        />
        <Earth />
      </Suspense>
    </Canvas>
  );
};

export default EarthCanvas;
```

Comment: I have hosted it on firebase, DNS is on cloudflare